# Efficient way to convert numpy record array to a list of dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

How do I convert the numpy record array below:

```
recs = [('Bill', 31, 260.0), ('Fred', 15, 145.0)]
r = rec.fromrecords(recs, names='name, age, weight', formats='S30, i2, f4')
```

to a list of dictionary like:

```
[{'name': 'Bill', 'age': 31, 'weight': 260.0}, 
'name': 'Fred', 'age': 15, 'weight': 145.0}]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answered at [Numpy-discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-February/048288.html) by Robert Kern

---

Copy of concluding email from that discussion:

> > How do I convert the numpy record array below:
> >     recs = [('Bill', 31, 260.0), ('Fred', 15, 145.0)]
> >     r = rec.fromrecords(recs, names='name, age, weight', formats='S30, i2, f4')
> >     to a list of dictionary like:
> >     [{'name': 'Bill', 'age': 31, 'weight': 260.0},
> >     'name': 'Fred', 'age': 15, 'weight': 145.0}]
>
> Assuming that your record array is only 1D:
>
> In [6]: r.dtype.names Out[6]: ('name', 'age', 'weight')
>
> In [7]: names = r.dtype.names
>
> In [8]: [dict(zip(names, record)) for record in r] Out[8]: [{'age':
>   31, 'name': 'Bill', 'weight': 260.0},  {'age': 15, 'name': 'Fred',
>   'weight': 145.0}]

Comment: -1, link only answers are strongly discouraged on SO.  If the link rots, then this answer becomes worse than not existing: maddening.

Comment: The link is gone already. A summary of the discussion would be great

Comment: The link's not gone, or was only temporarily gone. Downvoted answer, but added copy of the discussion conclusion in this answer. Which is the same solution as YOU's answer.

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure there is built-in function for that or not, but following could do the work.

```
>>> [dict(zip(r.dtype.names,x)) for x  in r]
[{'age': 31, 'name': 'Bill', 'weight': 260.0}, 
{'age': 15, 'name': 'Fred', 'weight': 145.0}]
```

Comment: Probably worth pulling `r.dtype.names` out to a local variable. Possibly `izip` is faster than `zip` as the number of records increases

Comment: This will only work for a one-dimensional array, not for zero-dimensional ones or multi-dimensional ones. It is also not recursive, but numpy structs can contain more structs or arrays

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the final structure required. This example shows a numpy recarray composed of several 1D subsets. To have a python dictionary instead, a possible conversion is:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.rec.array([np.array([1,3,6]), np.array([3.4,4.2,-1.2])], names=['t', 'x'])

b = {name:a[name] for name in a.dtype.names}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works in the following cases not covered by the other answers:

- 0-dimensional arrays (scalars). e.g. `np.array((1, 2), dtype=[('a', 'float32'), ('b', 'float32')])`
- elements of type `np.void` (result of indexing a record array)
- multi-dimensional arrays of structs
- structs containing structs, (e.g. `structured_to_dict(np.zeros((), dtype=[('a', [('b', 'float32', (2,))])]))`)
- Combinations of any of the above.

```py
def structured_to_dict(arr: np.ndarray):
    import numpy as np

    if np.ndim(arr) == 0:
        if arr.dtype.names == None:
            return arr.item()
        # accessing by int does *not* work when arr is a zero-dimensional array!
        return {k: structured_to_dict(arr[k]) for k in arr.dtype.names}
    return [structured_to_dict(v) for v in arr]
```

Comment: Is `structured_to_debug_dict` supposed to be `structured_to_dict`?

Comment: Excellent.  This appears to be a robust solution.  Very useful with `scipy.io.loadmat(file_name, squeeze_me=True)`.