# How do I coerce a python list of dictionaries containing date strings into a numpy record array of datetime objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

**This question is about the construction of a numpy record array from a list of dictionaries (as in the other question), but specifically for the datetime dtype. The method outlined there did not work for me. Read on -**

I have a Python 3 list of dictionaries, for example:

```
e = [{"date":"2019-11-07","value":3.147},{"date":"2019-11-08","value":2.7315}]
```

I want to convert `e` to a `numpy` record array/structure, and cast the date string to a `datetime` or `np.datetime64` object in one fell swoop.

But the following is not working: the date field is either still a string - not any sort of `datetime` object - or throws `ValueError Could not convert object to NumPy datetime`.

```
import numpy as np
what_goes_here = 'datetime64[s]' # or 'M8[D]', or..?
e_type = np.dtype([('date', what_goes_here), ('value', float)])
i = np.array(e, dtype=e_type)
```

Is there a way to achieve all this in one step and if so how?

Please no Python 2 or Pandas.

This is the opposite transformation to [Efficient way to convert numpy record array to a list of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203673/efficient-way-to-convert-numpy-record-array-to-a-list-of-dictionary) - plus the added `datetime` complication

Comment: Edited the Q - it's not a duplicate - neither that question nor its answers makes any reference to numpy datetime coercion - which is known to be a thorny topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value and saved as a list of tuples before casting the dtype to `datetime64` and `np.float`

```py
import numpy as np
e = [{"date": "2019-11-07", "value": 3.147},
     {"date": "2019-11-08", "value": 2.7315}]
e = [(d["date"], d["value"]) for d in e]
e = np.rec.array(e, dtype=[('date', 'datetime64[s]'), ('value', np.float)])
print('result: ', e)
print('data type of date: ', type(e.date[0]))

# print result
result:  [('2019-11-07T00:00:00', 3.147 ) ('2019-11-08T00:00:00', 2.7315)]
data type of date:  <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
```

Comment: Many thanks - apart from the definition of e_type in @b_c's answer, how are the two different? (trying to decide which to accept... :) )

Comment: You can check this link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html. 
@b_c use `datetime64[us]` so the string of date displays to milliseconds. My answer use `datetime64[s]` and displays to seconds only (not milliseconds). Is this what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21988714/4739755), conversion of datetime objects in numpy changed in 1.11.

Using a portion of the question from that link, this should give what you're looking for (with datetime numpy type explicitly specified):

```
import numpy as np

e = [{"date":"2019-11-07","value":3.147},{"date":"2019-11-08","value":2.7315}]
e_type = np.dtype([('date', 'datetime64[us]'), ('value', np.float)])

records = np.array([(x['date'], x['value']) for x in e],
                   dtype=e_type)

# Produces
array([('2019-11-07T00:00:00.000000', 3.147 ),
       ('2019-11-08T00:00:00.000000', 2.7315)],
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[us]'), ('value', '<f8')])

>>> records[0][0]
numpy.datetime64('2019-11-07T00:00:00.000000')
```

Comment: Many thanks - apart from the lack of definition of e_type in @Matt Wang's answer, how are the two different? (trying to decide which to accept... :) )

Comment: @jtlz2 In Matt's answer, the equivalent definition was put in directly as the parameter to `dtype` in the array call, while for mine I created a separate variable. The main differences though are: Matt creates a _record_ array (as requested) while mine makes a normal array (I missed that part). This changes how the array is represented somewhat, but also means he can do `e.date[0]` while I have to do `records[0][0]`. Matt also uses `'datetime64[s]'` while I use `'datetime64[us]'`. I'm not sure if this is an important difference though.

Comment: IMO, @Matt Wang answers your question more accurately, while the linked answer in mine adds some important context to _why_ this issue exists in the first place.